# open firefox from bash shells script in other desktop in ubuntu 12.10 (pear os 7)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, firefox, ubuntu-12.10

So I have figured out how to open Firefox from Bash.  It's pretty easy.

However, I would like it to open in my 2nd desktop, not the one I'm using.  So it doesn't bother my primary desktop.  How do I specify which desktop Firefox will open in?

I'm running Pear OS 7 which is basically Ubuntu 12.10.

Also is there a way to open Firefox without the GUI in the background?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: "Without the GUI in the background", this doesn't make a whole lot of sense, either you have an X-Server (or equivalent) running or you don't. If you don't, then you can run any GUI applications, if you do, you can run as many as you like.

Comment: similar to this, but the problem with wmctrl is that it moves the wrong window!  what if i'm working in firefox and I have a shell script that opens a new firefox window and does something in it, i only want it to move the newly opened window to the 2nd workspace/desktop not the one i'm using, if this makes sense?  basically, i dont want to know that bash opened anything...

Comment: yeah, i bascially just want to automate somethings in firefox using imacros because its just really easy, so if could simulate a gui and still run imacros for firefox i'd do it "without the gui"...  my main quuestion is just how to open just the new window into the 2nd, or other workspace/desktop...  i got the wmctrl to move my firefox into the 2nd workspace, but it moved the wrong one!

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose is here, if you're trying to automate a bunch of things on firefox using a script or similar, I'd suggest using something like selenium, (it's scriptable and should probably be able to do what you ask), but again your use case isn't very clear, what are you trying to automate, what does this script do and so on

Comment: that's not important, i just want to be able to open firefox in the 2nd workspace from a bash shell script... I figured it out by using wmctrl (had to install it)  but the problem now is that wmctrl moved the wrong firefox window to the 2nd workspace/desktop instead of the newly opened firefox window...

I got the wmctrl from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351154/open-applications-in-different-workspaces-in-gnome